# How to stop circular switching of workspaces in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, workspaces

I started using Xubuntu. There is one thing that is annoying me a bit.

I use a 2 X 2 layout for workspaces.

```
1  |  2
-------
3  |  4
```

When I was using Gnome, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> on workspace 1 did not do anyhting, but on Xfce, the default is that it switches to workspace 3. I searched, but could not find a way to stop this.

PS: What is this feature called?

Comment: Note: this also applies for Xfce in Fedora.

Answer (score 37):

In *settings manager - window manager tweaks - workspaces* you can control what happens when workspaces wrap.  Unticking the option shown in the image stops this "cycling" effect.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You probably want to disable this option in Settings > Settings Manager

[image]

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 5):

If you're a command-line nerd like me, you can type this into a terminal:

```
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/wrap_layout -t bool -s false
```

Comment: `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfwm4.xml`

Answer (score 0):

In case you do NOT have "XFCE Manager Tweaks" and cannot install them (like me), based on @bmaupin's answer and @Kevin's comment, the following worked for me:

1. Open the file `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfwm4.xml`,  in your favorite editor and then look for `wrap_layout` :

```
    ...
    <property name="use_compositing" type="bool" value="false"/>
    <property name="workspace_count" type="int" value="4"/>
    <property name="wrap_cycle" type="bool" value="true"/>
    <property name="wrap_layout" type="bool" value="false"/>
    ...
```

2. and change the value from `true` to `false`, as shown above.
3. Restart xfce4.

Kevin and bmaunpin have already answered, albeit a little unclearly.